# Microsoft Edge and Google Fonts show bold characters

Tags: html, css, fonts, microsoft-edge

In Microsoft Edge on Windows 10, all texts show UTF-8 characters in bold:

[image: white text on black, letters with macrons are bold]

I don’t know what’s the problem. Any solution?

Comment: This is most likely the problem of the font you use.

Comment: Please consider sharing some code, or an online example.

Comment: To answer this, more information is needed. Does this affect only one website, or all sites? Does the problem affect any other browsers, either on Windows 10 or on other OSes?

Comment: All bold characters have a [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron). The font probably does not support bold glyphs with this diacritic. Try another font for reference (standard fonts like Helvetica support a wide variety of diacritics in various font variants).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the 'bold' characters are in fact rendered in another font (which is probably not in bold, it just looks relatively thick compared to the Google font).

I checked your website and noticed in your styles.css that you are importing the font with:

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400,500,600);`

Try specifying the Extended Latin subset like this:

`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400,500,600&subset=latin-ext);`